# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, kotlin

I have been working on this project and everything seem perfect until about a week ago, I tried to launch the project on an emulator and ran into the error below.

```
$ yarn react-native run-android
yarn run v1.22.15
$ C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\.bin\react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1519 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (10, 37): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (119, 30): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (135, 26): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (155, 32): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (161, 31): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (169, 36): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactPlugin.kt: (99, 48):
'reactRoot: DirectoryProperty' is deprecated. reactRoot was confusing and has been replace with rootto point to your root project and reactNativeDir to point to the folder of the react-native NPM package
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (10, 37): 'ApplicationVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (11, 37): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (12, 37): 'LibraryVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (28, 51): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (131, 12): 'ApplicationVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (132, 12): 'LibraryVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (250, 14): 'BaseVariant' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava

> Configure project :app
Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version. Class name for the included build object: org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuild$IncludedBuildImpl_Decorated.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
Note: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\codegen\generator\SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> Configuration with name 'compile' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\codegen\generator\SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> Configuration with name 'compile' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 4s

    at makeError (C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Chifes\Desktop\apps\RoGoods\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is my package.json content

```
{
  "name": "RoGoods",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.2",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "*",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.17.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.17.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.17.8",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Over the past week, I have tried everything to fix this error but nothing seem to work. I have uninstalled most of the packages, but can't seem to figure what the problem is. Any help will be richly appreciated.